# RUBY: Get the Steam Username from OmniAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, steam-web-api

I have been using Omniauth to retrieve an environment that contains the steam username.

The output looks like this:

```
<OmniAuth::AuthHash::InfoHash image="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d4/d45a66fee7932d270ec32d4457d865b485245cf1_medium.jpg" location="YT, CA" name="Daiki" nickname="Corybantic Walrus" urls=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash FriendList=#<URI::HTTP:0x0000000614f590 URL:http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetFriendList/v0001/?key=4A8837BF7A6C439681B57F4962D8B011&steamid=76561198128055024&relationship=friend> Profile="http://steamcommunity.com/id/hatterkiller/">> provider="steam" uid="76561198128055024">
```

I don't really know how to format this inside Stack Overflow, so here is a cleaner [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/djqUwsyv).

The information I need is inside the     `<Omniauth::AuthHash::Infohash` thing of the code. Is there a way to use Ruby to retrieve the username (nickname) and to put it inside an array?

Sort of like this, but this only worked for the previous output format:

```
    auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']

 session[:current_user] = { :nickname => auth.info['nickname'],
                                      :image => auth.info['image'],
                                      :uid => auth.uid }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
session[:current_user] = {
  nickname: auth[:info][:nickname],
  image:    auth[:info][:image],
  uid:      auth[:uid]
}
```

Comment: where come `auth`variable, from `request.env["omniauth.auth"]`?

Comment: Oh sorry!     auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']

Comment: It's simple, before assign `session[:current_user]` try to do `logger.info auth.inspect` to assure that have values.

Comment: Ok. So they do have values. I managed to "puts" them onto my output index.erb page, with the following `{"nickname"=>"Corybantic Walrus", "image"=>"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d4/d45a66fee7932d270ec32d4457d865b485245cf1_medium.jpg", "uid"=>"76561198128055024"}` as the output.  My current  `<p><%= session[:current_user][:nickname] %></p>` in the index erb isn't working. Is there another way?

Comment: try with `session[:current_user] = {
  nickname: request.env["omniauth.auth"][:info][:nickname],
  image:    request.env["omniauth.auth"][:info][:image],
  uid:      request.env["omniauth.auth"][:uid]
}`